# Update exiting JSON dynamically by adding new object or replacing

Tags: json, dynamic

I have a addressInfo json object like below. I need to update this dynamically based on 3 scenarios:

```
{
        "addressInfo": {
        }
    
}
```

1. When atlease one of cityInfo object is present, add the new one and modify JSON to below. Note('cityInfo' property is removed)

   {
   "addressInfo": {
   "cityInfo":
   {
   "cityName": "Chicago",
   "cityZip": "60007",
   }
   }
   should be changed to
   "addressInfo": {
   filters":[
   {
   "cityName": "Chicago",
   "cityZip": "60007",
   },
   {
   "cityName": "New York",
   "cityZip": "10001"
   }
   ]
   }
   }
2. When none one of cityInfo oject is present under addressInfo, add the new one and modify JSON to below.

   {
   "addressInfo": {

   ```
       }
   ```

   }

should be changed to

```
{
        "addressInfo": {
            "cityInfo": 
                {
                    "cityName": "Chicago",
                    "cityZip": "60007"
                }
        }
}
```

3. When more than one of cityInfo object is present, add the new one and modify JSON to below.

   {
   "addressInfo": {
   filters":[
   {
   "cityName": "Chicago",
   "cityZip": "60007",
   },
   {
   "cityName": "New York",
   "cityZip": "10001"
   }
   ]
   }
   }

should be changed to

```
{
        "addressInfo": {
    filters":[
        {
            "cityName": "Chicago",
            "cityZip": "60007", 
        },
                        {
            "cityName": "New York",
            "cityZip": "10001"
        },
       {
            "cityName": "San Francisco",
            "cityZip": "94016"
        }
    ]
}
```

}
I am looking some solution in javascript.

Comment: What language do you want to do this in? Please tag your question appropriately

Comment: Why change the name of the element from `cityInfo` to `filters`? It would seem it would make your code a lot more complicated than it needs to be?

Comment: @Nick, I updated it. I am looking into something in javascript. Changing from cityInfo to filters, it is the way it is designed.